# Generate multi dimensional array with key value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, brackets

I have an array from json like this:

```
{"1001":"Account1","1002":"Account2","1003":"Account3"}
```

and i need convert it to key value format:

```
[{id:"1001",name:"Account1"},
{id:"1002",name:"Account2"},
{id:"1003",name:"Account3"}]
```

To do this i wrote this function:

```
function arrayToMultiArray(list) {
    var matrix = [], i;
    i = -1;
    for (var key in list) {
        i++;
        matrix[i] = [];
        matrix[i].push({"id":key, "name":list[key]});
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

but the generated array has brackets for each array

```
[[{id:"1001",name:"Account1"}],
[{id:"1002",name:"Account2"}],
[{id:"1003",name:"Account3"}]]
```

How can i remove brackets of internal arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You added array in array.

Just change

```
i++;
matrix[i] = [];
matrix[i].push({"id":key, "name":list[key]});
```

to

```
matrix.push({"id":key, "name":list[key]});
```

Answer (score 1):

you are creating a multidimensional array.

remove this

```
 i++;
 matrix[i] = [];
```

and do this directly

```
matrix.push({"id":key, "name":list[key]});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the same with `Object.keys` and `Array.prototype.map`

```js
var obj = {"1001":"Account1","1002":"Account2","1003":"Account3"};
var arr = Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
  return { id : key, name : obj[key] }
});

console.log(arr);
```